# Powershell [double]::parse() issue

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

```
"1,4" -as[double]          # 14 ???
"1.4" -as[double]          # 1,4

[convert]::ToDouble("1,4") # 1,4
[convert]::ToDouble("1.4") # Error
```

It looks like a joke.
What is the universal method to get double from any forms of representation? I thought, that posh can understand only "1.4" form(with dot). But no, he can work with "1,4"(with comma) too. So why i cant find the normal method of parsing numbers? Need help with it)

Comment: Parsing is locale dependent. Which one do you use?

Comment: Parsing is gotten from Globalization settings.  So you need to set the culture with parsing.  So use something like this :             System.Globalization.CultureInfo info = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            double.Parse("double",info);  //

Comment: You can specify culture in ToDouble. In your case I assume this would work
    [convert]::ToDouble("1,4", [CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture) 
    [convert]::ToDouble("1.4", [CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)